# TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Gente tengo un problema con este código:

```
def task_get_data_misindicadores():
    url = 'https://*****.co/api/*****/{0}/'.format(
        config.MI_APIKEY
    )
    req = requests.get(url)
    if not req.ok:
        return 'Timeout Error'

    to_cache = []
    try:
        for indicator in req.json():
            if indicator['updated_at'] is None:
                continue

            if indicator['is_public']:
                updated_at = timesince(datetime.strptime(
                    indicator['updated_at'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
                ))

                to_cache.append({
                    'name': indicator['name'],
                    'value': "{0:0.0f}".format(float(indicator['measured_value'])),
                    'url': 'https://*****.co{0}'.format(
                    indicator['url']
                ),
                    'trend': indicator['trend'],
                    'heat': indicator['heat'],
                    'metric_units': indicator['metric_units'],
                    'goal': indicator['goal'],
                    'updated_at': updated_at,
                })
    except TypeError:
        pass

    if len(to_cache) > 0:
        cache.set('mis_indicadores_list', to_cache, 3600)
        return True

    return False
```

resulta que siempre que llega a la linea `for indicator in req.json():` lanza la excepción, he intentado de todas formas convertirlo a string pero fallo.

Utilizo esto dentro de una tarea de celery, cuando lo hago por shell_plus corre perfecto pero en celery siempre falla.

utilizo:

1. Django 1.8.13
2. Python 3.5

Python 3.5

¿alguna idea de como evitar este error?

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes mostar el script completo que usas con Celery?

Comment: Hola @César edite la entrada con el código completo, y de paso actualice algunas cosas.

Comment: ¿En alguna parte del proceso estás haciendo `app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')`? Donde `app` es la instancia de Celery creada con, por ejemplo, `app = Celery('test')`

Comment: Si, el proceso corre junto con otras tareas que tengo pero en esta tara puntual se revienta al llegar a la linea

Comment: Si puedes, mira a ver si las cabeceras de la petición especifican el Content-type correcto. Quizás no sea json.

Comment: Posiblemente, el servidor no esté enviando la cabecera `Content-Type` para indicar que se trata de contenido json. Te podemos dar algunos *workarounds* al problema, pero tal vez deberías mirar primero qué envía el servidor (eg: `req.headers`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer hubo algún problema con los archivos cuando pase Python de 2.7 a 3.5, borre todo y copie de nuevo y fue todo, ahora funciona bien.